# SSH wrong user name

Tags: ssh

I connected to my PC from my android via SSH and when i enter w or who command to list all users logged in I get two of my same PC user names instead of my Android name.

Ex;

PC name - Atlas 192.168.0.1
Android - Piston 192.168.0.2

When I give command, I get two Atlas's - one on first line and second same name on the next (but with my android IP 192.168.0.2 not my PC's 192.168.0.1 - that's how I know it's connected) but shouldn't be my android name Piston shows on the second line?

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Atlas is your username on the PC.

sshd does not ask for (and does not care about) any other usernames you may be using on other machines.